# scan character array in C language

Tags: c, arrays, character

I want to scan a character array as input as shown below and I also want to get the number of rows from the user (it's a square matrix).

> O O X
>   O X O
>   O O X

but when I scan it using the program below, it only scans two rows.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int size,i,j;
    printf("Enter size");
    scanf("%d",&size);

    int a[size][size];

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        for(j=0;j<size;j++)
            scanf("%c",&a[i][j]);

}
```

The output which I'm getting is:

> Enter size3
>   O O X
>   O X O

then it's not asking for the last row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the whitespace is not skipped here..

this would fix it, it would also *consume* the whitespace:

```
scanf(" %c",&a[i][j]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, I don't have enough reputation to comment. In addition to Yohannes' answer, consider what kind of input you are expecting. You use an integer array to store values, but you tell `scanf` to expect characters with the `"%c"`. Maybe use character array or take integers as input and get rid of type mismatch warning from the compiler.

`scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);` to read integers